# Apex Application pointing to deleted page

Tags: oracle-apex

I recently created a login page with Page# as **10009** to do some testing with a Test Authorization scheme. I have reverted from the authorization scheme and deleted the login page 10009, leaving login page 9999 that was already there.

However, I'm trying to run my application and it's saying `Application "100" Page "login10009" not found.`

Can you tell me where my application may be pointing to that might still have an instance of the deleted page **10009**

Answer (score 2):

Go to your application's shared components -> User interface attributes -> Home URL and check if it is pointing to the deleted login screen. If so, change it to your real login page.

Comment: I had found it and forgot to come back and check. But this is correct and I thank you for responding. I have a question I am going to post now about an ORA-29273 error in my Apex application. Please take a look at it.